# Dropbox api How can I get files from dropbox shared link

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I dear,

I am trying to write a module for Prestashop that downloads files contained in a Dropbox link.

My link looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ognd7avuw63pm8s/AABl5K_uZY1RKGp5SbY__nD5a?dl=0

How can I get files info and files content from this link using Dropbox api

many Thanks

Comment: Unless one of the cryptic values from that URL can be used as identifier for the relevant object in the API, you probably won't be able to do this. Instead of having such share links given to you, you should then perhaps implement the whole thing via API in the first place (get the user's permission, then read _all_ their dropbox content, and let them choose which folder they want your system to download from.)

Answer (score 0):

If the shared link is publicly accessible without a password, you can download directly from the shared link as documented here:

https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/force-download

Otherwise, you can use the Dropbox API functionality here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file